# Null object reference on view visibility

Tags: java, android, class

I have a class that extends another class. When this class is called, it is supposed to setup variables and other classes as needed. However, the XML elements are coming back null.

The base class:

```
public abstract class Shop implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    public interface Task {
        void completed();
    }

    public Button identifyBtn;
    public abstract void setup();
    public final void build() {
        setup();
    }

    ....
}
```

The class being instantiated:

```
public class Weapons extends Shop {
    public String shopName = "Ye Aulde Smithery";

    public Weapons(){
        super();
        type = "weapons";
    }

    public void setup(){
        setTitle(shopName);
        identifyBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        npcImg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.npc_weapons);
        blurb.setText(generateBlurb(R.array.bill_smith_blurbs));

        getItems(new Shop.Task() {
            @Override
            public void completed() {
                displayList(items);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then, in the onCreate method of the calling Activity, I've got:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop);
    activity = this;

    app.stats.addObserver(new StatBar());
    app.stats.setState();

    final String type = getIntent().getStringExtra("type");

    switch(type){
        case "trade":
            shop = new Trade();
            break;

        case "shop_armor":
            shop = new Armor();
            break;

        case "shop_weapons":
            shop = new Weapons();
            break;

        case "shop_tavern":
            shop = new Tavern();
            break;

        case "shop_healer":
            shop = new Healer();
            break;

        case "shop_court":
            shop = new Court();
            break;

        case "shop_post_office":
            shop = new PostOffice();
            break;

        case "shop_smithy":
            shop = new Smithy();
            break;

        case "shop_guild":
            shop = new Skill();
            break;

        case "gems":

            break;

        case "shop_diner":

            break;

        case "storage":
            shop = new Storage();
            break;

        case "shop_den":

            break;

        case "shop_inn":

            break;
    }
    shop.items = new ArrayList<>();
    shop.content = findViewById(R.id.shop_bottom_right);
    shop.npcImg = findViewById(R.id.shop_npc);
    shop.exit = findViewById(R.id.exitBtn);
    shop.tradeBtn = findViewById(R.id.tradeBtn);
    shop.switchBtn = findViewById(R.id.switchBtn);
    shop.infoBtn = findViewById(R.id.infoBtn);
    shop.polishBtn = findViewById(R.id.polishBtn);
    shop.identifyBtn = findViewById(R.id.identifyBtn);
    shop.blurb = findViewById(R.id.shop_blurb);

    shop.build();
}
```

Everything builds fine, but when I run the Shop in my game, I keep getting that the line `identifyBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` is throwing:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

What would be causing this and how can I work around the problem?

EDIT - posting the XML resource:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/shop_layout_container"
             tools:context="com.therealmsbeyond.dragoncourtmobile.ActivityShop">
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout_container">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/nextReset"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/shop_top_right">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/exitBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/exit"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tradeBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/trade"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/exitBtn"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/exitBtn"/>
            <RadioGroup
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/tradeBtn"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tradeBtn"
                android:id="@+id/switchBtn">
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/shop_buy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Buy"
                    android:onClick="onShopToggle"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/shop_sell"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Sell"
                    android:onClick="onShopToggle"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shop_top_right"
            android:contentDescription="@string/shop_char"
            android:id="@+id/shop_npc"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shop_npc"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/shop_blurb"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shop_blurb"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Info"
            android:id="@+id/infoBtn"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/infoBtn"
            android:text="Identify $40"
            android:id="@+id/identifyBtn"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/infoBtn"
            android:text="Polish $40"
            android:id="@+id/polishBtn"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/shop_blurb"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/shop_blurb"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shop_top_right"
            android:id="@+id/shop_bottom_right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40sp">

        </RelativeLayout>
        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottom_bar_inc"
            layout="@layout/stat_bar"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Edit 2 - debug info

i did a quick and dirty `Log.i()` of the button in the Activity after the class is instantiated but before the build method is called and got `I/identifyBtn: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{8c6d7d0 GFED..C.. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0900e2 app:id/identifyBtn}`, so I'm assuming the button is being referenced correctly. However it remains unavailable to the class.

Comment: Can you show your layout xml?  Does the scene look correct if you comment out that line?

Comment: @Buddy updated. commenting doesn't help because there are other views being referenced that will also throw the exception.

Comment: this code looks fine. It should work. can your post your on create method. also check logcat again and see if it is the same line

Comment: Down voted, why?

Answer (score -1):

Cleaned and rebuilt and it works fine now...